# html taglib struts

Tags: jsp, struts, taglib, htmltext, actionform

Good afternoon in my timezone.

I have a few little doubts regarding the use of this tag library and the actionForm.
I want to put a inputText in my page , but this input text will be read only.So i did not put any thing in the actionForm object because this is a readOnly text(just to display data).
I put the information in the request scope (request.setAttribute("readOnly","data")).
In my jsp i have

```
<html:form action="action1">
    <html:text name="actionForm" property="inputText1"/>
    <html:text name="actionForm" property="inputText2"/>
    <html:text property="readOnly" readonly="true"/>
<html:form>
```

This is not working(if i remove the last field everything works fine), so i put the following questions ?
Is it possible using `<html:text>` to access attributes in any scope,regardless the actionForm bean ?The documentation provide us with two properties to define the bean from where we want to retrieve the values (name=name of the bean and property=name of the property inside the bean).But it does not say anything about scopes(requst,scope).
So can i use this taglibrary or i have to go by another way ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The `property` attribute, used alone, is assumed to refer to an `ActionForm` property.

In general, an `ActionForm` property is the preferred way to send form elements to the view layer. If you're not using the normal mechanism, you need to provide the `name` attribute to explicitly dis-associate the input form element from the `ActionForm` in scope.

You may also use a plain HTML tag and use JSP EL to provide the value, or not use an input tag at all and simply display the value.